# Matplotlib: Incompatible library version: _imaging.cpython-38-darwin.so requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 10.0.0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, import

I'm attempting to simply import the matplotlib module into my version of Python3 (3.10) on MacOS Big Sur.

However, when I simply try to `import matplotlib`, I get the following error:

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/.dylibs/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib and libtiff, as well as trying to install matplotlib in a different python virtual environment - nothing seems to work.

I found [this link](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/2870) which has my exact error message, but as far as I can tell involves a completely different app (Inkscape vs. matplotlib), and the fix seems to be installing a different version of Inkscape. To me, this didn't seem relevant, and none of the other solutions found after googling seemed to work for my specific situation. Any ideas?

Comment: You don’t say anything about _how_ you are installing any of these.    Strongly suggest simply using conda and/or mamba

Comment: @JodyKlymak I've been installing and uninstalling things with a mix of homebrew and pip3. I just tried to download conda and create a conda environement with 'conda create --name graphingPy python=3.10 pandas numpy matplotlib', but am getting a very similar error even after this, with the version required now 11.0.0 instead of 14.0.0

Comment: Did you activate that environment before trying to use it?   Also, are you doing this from the command line?  If you are getting the same error with Conda, odds are you are using the same python from before, and not the conda python.  Check doing `which python`

Comment: First, thanks for the help on this! I did activate the environment, I'm using command line, and confirmed that I'm using the anaconda version of python when typing 'which python'. Still though, the error is persistent! Tempted to just do a full reinstall, but I have some environments that still work and I'd prefer not to ruin :(